# How to get a Cursor trail effect on a HTML page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am learning jquery, and i am trying to figure out how i can add a trail effect to the mouse as it moves around a HTML page
Thanks.

Comment: Yes otherwise they couldnt have created it......

Comment: "Best comment of the day"-award goes to @RickBronger

Comment: lol petty @RickBronger

Comment: This is not a site that gives you code examples. Try to write your own code and if you are stuck come back here to ask help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible to replicate the effect. Lets see how it was implemented first:

1) Create an in-memory canvas with dimensions equal to the window. This canvas will be used as the mask.

2) Attach a mousemove handler to the document. When called, it stores the cursor’s coordinates and the current timestamp.

3) Join the mouse coordinates into a path and stroke it on the mask canvas with a blurred shadow.

4) Fade path segments to transparent after one second.

5) Vary the width of path segments based on cursor speed (calculated as the distance between adjacent points). Slow movement results in thick lines, fast movement results in thin.

6) Prepare a blurred and darkened version of the image that is to be revealed and make it the page background.

7) Add a canvas to the document with dimensions equal to the window.

8) Render the original image to the document canvas.

9)Render the mask canvas to the document canvas using the destination-in compositing operation — this masks existing canvas content.

Credits: [Chris Doble](https://stackoverflow.com/users/94896/chris-doble)

Find it here: [5 Visual Effects Canva Uses to Thrill Users](https://engineering.canva.com/2016/05/16/five-visual-effects/)

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

checkout this solutions here :  https://github.com/Masth0/ScratchCard

Also you can search for "scratch card" on google and find many codepan.io board.